# Get access to all spring beans of a given type

Tags: java, spring, proxy, javabeans, spring-batch

I have a Spring application (Spring Batch not web application). In a test class, I want to grab access to all of my beans of a given type.  
I understand that in Spring you should generally use IOC and let the container inject your beans. However in this case, I want to loop through a variable number of beans that extend a given class (org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader), and do something (want it to be a unit/integration test that just connects it to the database and reads 1 row, so we can confirm at test time that all of the JdbcCursorItemReader in the system have valid SQL and row mappers).

Problem 1) I can only get beans one at a time. I can have my class **implement BeanFactoryAware** to get a reference to my beanfactory. Then I can do **beanFactory.getBean("name");** to get access to a single bean. How do I instead get ALL beans? I can loop through and drop the ones that aren't the class I want.. but somehow I need a list of all beans the beanfactory knows about or something.

Problem 2) The bean I get back from the beanfactory is a proxy. If I try to cast and use my bean I get something like
**java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get around the first problem by using `ApplicationContextAware` instead of `BeanFactoryAware`. This will pass in the `ApplicationContext`, which has the `getBeansOfType()` method which lets you retrieve all beans that are of a given type.

The second problem is likely caused because something is creating AOP proxies around your `JdbcCursorItemReader` bean. These generated proxies will, by default, implement the same interfaces that `JdbcCursorItemReader` does (specifically, `ItemReader` and `ItemStream`). Your code should not try and cast to the class type (`JdbcCursorItemReader`), but to one of those interface types instead.  It's usually possible to force the proxy to extend the proxied class directly, but without knowing anything about your setup, I can't help you with that.

Comment: Can I cast it to ItemReader and just use it? And the proxy magic will give me the real reader? Hummmm spring is complicated sometimes

Comment: @bwawok: Yes, casting to `ItemReader` should work fine. Just don't try and cast to `JdbcCursorItemReader`.

Comment: @skaffman: but what if I have to do something like this                           ((JdbcCursorItemReader) itemReader).open(executionContext);